# How can I quickly run the last-executed script in VSCode (not the script I'm currently viewing/editing), as one can do in PyCharm?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I have been giving VSCode a serious try after using PyCharm for many years. I am enjoying it, but there are some things I can't quite figure out. Here is something that I have done many times within PyCharm:

1. Run a file, say main.py, by Ctrl+Shift+F10 (runs selected code).
2. Inspect output.
3. Change supplemental_code.py.
4. Re-run main.py by Ctrl+F10 (notice the lack of "Shift". This re-runs last executed script).

In VSCode I only see a way to run the selected script. Is there any way to achieve the behavior I'm gotten accustomed to, but within VSCode?

Answer (score 0):

In PyCharm:

**Ctrl+Shift+F10**: run the current file.

**Shift+F10**: run the file which you configured.

**Shift+F9**: debug the file which you configured.

In VSCode:

**Run Python File in Terminal**: run the current file.

Through click the top right green triangle or right-click in the file and select this command. It has no shortcut in default, but you can modify it by yourself. Equal to **Ctrl+Shift+F10** in PyCharm.

There is no way to configure the file which `Python File in Terminal` command to execute. So that's impossible to get an equal effect like `Shift+F10` in PyCharm.

But you can configure in the `launch.json` like this to get the equal effect like **Shift+F9** in PyCharm:

from:

```
"program": "${file}", //means the current file.
```

to:

```
"program": "${workspaceFolder}/xxx/xxx.py", //specific way to the file you want to execute. ${workspaceFolder} means the path of the folder opened in VS Code.
```

Comment: your approach only works if I want to keep running the same code over and over again. If I understand correctly, you are re-mapping "Run & Debug" to debugging a particular file. Whereas the behavior I want is to re-run (or re-debug, perhaps) the last file that I ran/debugged. It seems that you are saying you are not aware of a way to do this in VSCode, is that right?

Comment: @Lepidopterist Hi, you could reach that in the PyCharm? I mean re-run (or re-debug, perhaps) the last file that I ran/debugged. In the PyCharm it's also appointing a particular file I think.

Comment: Sorry I am not quite understanding. In PyCharm as soon as I run a file, it is somehow saved as "the last file that I ran". So that if I do Shift+F10 it will re-run that last file. The solution you're proposing seems to require that I hardcode, in advance, the file I would like to run multiple times.